# Use Angular Material in Custom Library along Main app

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material-7

I had two Angular 5 who shared some components, so far I've been replicating the code.
I've recently migrated to angular 7 in order to create a shared library.
Now the problem is I use AngularMaterial and FlexLayout on the main apps and I want also to use it on the Library project.

Can I import Angular Material modules on the AppModule along in the CustomLibrary?
I've been having problems importing FlexLayout on both sides, I'm having Static Injector Errors, but if I remove the FlexLayout import from library project, I got no errors but I can't use it on Lib components.